# when a closed map is locally affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Exercise 12.3 of the Gortz and Wedhorn book says that if $f:X \to Y$ is a closed map between two schemes and $y\in Y$ is a point such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is contained in some open affine subspace of $X$ then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ such that the morphism $f:f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is affine.

I can't solve this problem and my main problem is that why if you take an open affine neighborhood of $y$ then I'm not sure why there exist an open affine neighborhood of $f^{-1}(y)$ inside $f^{-1}(U)$. I can prove that this is equivalent to the problem.

this is problem three and we don't even have any finiteness condition so It shouldn't be hard but I don't have any idea. any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can do it when $Y$ is separated, but I don’t know about the general case...

Comment: @Mindlack seperated is good enough for me. how you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V \subset X$ be an open affine subset containing $f^{-1}(y)$. Then $F=X\backslash V$ be a closed subset of $X$, so that $U_1=Y \backslash f(F)$ is an open subset of $Y$ containing $y$.

Let $U \subset U_1$ be an affine open subset containing $y$: then $f^{-1}(U)=X \times_Y U=V \times_Y U$.

Assume $Y$ is separated, then $V \times_Y U \rightarrow V\times_{\mathbb{Z}} U$ is a closed immersion to an affine scheme so that $V \times_Y U=f^{-1}(U)$ is affine.

Comment: Yes – and by definition $f^{-1}(U) \subset f^{-1}(U_1)=f^{-1}(Y \backslash f(X\backslash V))=X \backslash f^{-1}(f(X \backslash V))$, and, if $x \notin f^{-1}(f(X \backslash V))$, then $f(x) \notin f(X \backslash V)$, so $x \notin X \backslash V$ thus $x \in V$. So $X \backslash f^{-1}(f(X \backslash V)) \subset V$ hence $f^{-1}(U) \subset V$.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your proof

Comment: so basically you are saying that any morphism from an affine scheme to a separated scheme is affine.thank you!

Comment: @ali: hm... yes. Actually there’s something more general: let $\mathcal{P}$ be a property of morphisms that contains closed immersions and is stable under base change and composition. Let $X/S$ be $\mathcal{P}$, $Y/S$ be separated, then any $S$-morphism $X \rightarrow Y$ is $\mathcal{P}$, because then this map is $X=X \times_Y Y \rightarrow X \times_S Y \rightarrow Y$, the first one is a closed immersion and the second one is a base change of $X/S$. In your last comment $\mathcal{P}$ refers to the morphism being affine.

Comment: I know I just does not think of using it

Comment: (“$\mathcal{P}$ contains closed immersions” meaning that “closed immersions satisfy $\mathcal{P}$”, not the inverse).